# How to open Coyote Navigation System on iOS devices with a url scheme

Tags: ios, url, gps, url-scheme

I'm trying to open a navigation in the Coyote app (https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/coyote-alertes-gps-trafic/id367345773?mt=8) via an url scheme like I do for Waze or GoogleMaps.

You can see examples for those apps here: https://github.com/zirinisp/PazMapDirections/blob/master/PazMapDirections/PazMapDirections.swift

After having downloaded the app and opened the `Info.plist` I've discovered it registered the `coyote://` and the `icoyote://` url schemes.

Unfortunately I don't know the format to use to pass the GPS coordinates to the app.

If someone can help...